# Why did my whole milk go bad faster than skim milk?

Tags: milk, spoilage

Why did my whole milk curdle and get yucky and smell before my skim milk when left out?  I thought it was supposed to be the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

Bad luck.

There isn't consensus on which would spoil faster.

Apparently there has been a [controlled study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12222801) that found that skim spoiled faster but the difference was slight. It would have to be in a controlled environment. At home, with all the other variables involved, it would look much more random.

[Does whole milk spoil faster than skim milk?](http://recipes.howstuffworks.com/does-whole-milk-spoil-faster-than-skim-milk.htm)

Comment: Specifically, spoiling is due to bacterial contamination, so it's all down to what managed to get into the milk when you've opened it, which is completely luck.

Comment: Whoever drinks right from the carton likes whole milk...;-)